# Angular2 http.get from Restful Webservice when i run this below code i am getting error status 200, URL null

Tags: java, angular, typescript

### Angular2 http.get from Restful Webservice when i run this below code i am getting error  status 200, URL null

when am tiring jsontest.com am getting value properly

```
 getCurrentTime()
    {
    //return this.http.get('http://date.jsontest.com')
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/webserviceangular2/services/updateUserRecords/')
    .map(res=>res.json());
    }
```

### my another component.ts page

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {FormExample} from "./angular-typescript-form.component";
import {Jsonp, URLSearchParams} from 'angular2/http'; 
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `<angular-typescript-form>loading...</angular-typescript-form>    <br>
<p>{{postData}}</p>
<button (click)="OnTestGet()">Test_get_request</button>
<p>{{getData |json}}</p>
`,
directives: [FormExample],
providers: [FormExample,JSONP_PROVIDERS]
})
export class FormComponent {
constructor(private httpservice: FormExample){}
getData: string;
OnTestPost(){
this.httpservice.postJSON()
}
OnTestGet()
{
this.httpservice.getCurrentTime()
.subscribe(
data=>console.log(this.getData=data),
error=>console.log(JSON.stringify(error)),
()=> console.log("finished"));
}
}
```

### Below is my java code

```
@Path("/updateManager")
public class UpdateManager {
@GET
@Produces("text/plain")
@Consumes("text/plain")
//@Produces("application/json")
//@Consumes("application/json")
@Path("/updateUserRecords/")
public Response updateUserRecords(){        
try {
dbConnection = getDBConnection();
System.out.println("connected is created "+dbConnection);
myStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement("select * from account");
System.out.println(myStatement);
rs = myStatement.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {         
data=rs.getString(3);                                   
}           
ResponseBuilder rb=Response.status(200);
rb.cacheControl(cc);
rb.entity(data);
response=rb.build();            
}catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println(e);
}       
return response;    
}
```

am getting payload value in java restful webservice but client side am getting error, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

i think you are sending text in response change your `@consume` and`@produces` as `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON),@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` it can send response in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Actually There is no change, it causes cross origin problem, i added below code at the last place of the tomcat7/conf/web.xml file. Now its working fine..

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
    <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
    <param-value>10</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```